# How to limit number off ssh login attempts per time interval

Tags: ssh, firewall

I am trying to limit number of ssh login attempts per time period. How might I do that?

I have something like (in shorewall's rules)

```
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE
MARK
#                                                       PORT    PORT(S)

...
Limit:info:SSHA,3,180   net     all     tcp     22
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `iptables` to limit to 3 attempts per minute:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
```

Or use something like  [`fail2ban`](http://www.fail2ban.org/). It bans by IP address for 15 minutes after 5 unsuccesfull login attempts.

Comment: OK, now it blocks me out, how do i remove this? I saved it too i think ...  i dont see anything like what I typed in `iptables -L` or `-S`. also cant find it in history

Comment: The easiest way is flushing all INPUT rules with `iptables -F INPUT`.

Comment: by flush you mean commit or remove?

Comment: I mean "remove".

Answer (score 0):

There are different tools to do this, like denyhosts
 http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/